# Server Configuration Sys.Webforms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I'm working in a web application that work in asp.net with ajax but I have a problem, I'm having the message error:

Sys.Webforms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried all the options of: http://forums.asp.net/t/1069384.aspx but don't work!

I don`t know what's the problem, because I have two servers and they're one where the application have not problem, and the other with the same configuration and the same application have the problem. So I don't know if the problem is the server configuration, I need a clue, please help me!, I'm 10 days with the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problom!
One server, two website with one compilation. one is ok and the other throw **Sys.Webforms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an objec**t error